# python 7z extraction with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, 7zip

I try extract my archive using the subprocess:

> subprocess.call(['7z', 'x', '-r', '-y', '-o %s' %
>   os.path.normpath("C:/temp"), archivePath], shell = True)

but I get an error:

> 7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
>
> Processing archive: \172.16.0.30\TestFarm\testdata\testdata.7z
>
> Error: Can not create output directory  C:\temp\
>
> System error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
>   incorrect.
>
> 2

How can I do it? Why it happens? If I use command line console it work perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set shell=False .

Set the output directory to be '-o%s' % directory.

You are prepending a space before the directory on the 7z command line.